# Как определить переменную в функции?

Tags: javascript

Имею строку вида: `` let a = `text ${variable} text ${variable} text` ``

Хочу заполнить переменные чем-то из функции.
`someFunction(a)`

Пытался так:

```
function replace(literals, ...variable) {
    let concatResult = "";
    let changeOn = "aaaaaaa"
    const variableChanged = variable.map((evenItem) => {return evenItem = changeOn});
    //Конкатенация строковых литералов и подстановок.
    for (let i = 0; i < variableChanged.length; i++) {
        concatResult += literals[i] + variableChanged[i];
    }
    //Присоединение последнего элемента из массива литералов, массив literals всегда на один элемент больше, чем массив variable.
    concatResult += literals[literals.length - 1];
    return concatResult;
}
```

Однако, при такой предаче `` replace`text ${variable} text ${variable} text` `` все работает.
А вот переменную "a" туда не передать.

Есть идеи?

Answer (score 0):

Насклько я понимаю, вы хотите использовать функцию для шаблонных строк как обычную функцию. К сожалению, использовать её с тем же видом шаблонной строки не получится — при вызове таких функций движок сам разбирает строку на массив литералов и значение переменных, тогда как при передаче такой строки в обычный вызов функции строка сначала подвергнется интерполяции переменных и будет передана уже единой простой строкой. Единственный способ достигнуть того, что вам нужно (идентичного поведения при обычном вызове), это самому разобрать строку на составляющие:

```js
replace(['text ', ' text ', ' text'], variable, variable);
```

Но такая сложность вряд ли оправдана, даже если её как-то автоматизировать.

Возможно, вам стоит дополнить вопрос, объяснив, зачем вам такое злоупотребление функциями для шаблонных строк)